# Why am I not getting points around clusers in this kmeans implementation?

Tags: r, k-means

In below kmeans analysis I am assigning a 1 or 0 to indicate if word is associated with a user :

```
cells = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
rnames = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9")
cnames = c("google","so","test")

x <- matrix(cells, nrow=9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(rnames, cnames))

# run K-Means
km <- kmeans(x, 3, 15)

# print components of km
print(km)

# plot clusters
plot(x, col = km$cluster)
# plot centers
points(km$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8)
```

This is the graph :

[image]

Why do I not receive multiple points around each cluster ? What is this graph indicating. I would like to suggest a word to a user depending on if another use has the same word configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see multiple points because your data are discrete, categorical observations.  K-means is really only suitable for grouping continuous observations.  Your data can only appear on three points on the plot you've shown and three points don't make a nice "cloud" of data.

This suggests to me that k-means is probably not appropriate for your specific problem.

Incidentally, when I run the code above, I get the plot below, which is different from the one you've shown us.  Perhaps this is more like what you are expecting?  The green green data point belongs to (is "around") the upper-right cluster centre indicated by a black asterisk.

[image]

Comment: there is something strange happening as when I re-run I get same result as above, except a black circle instead of green in top right corner

Comment: Well, the k-means algorithm is stochastic: it depends on picking random initial guesses for the positions of the cluster centres, so it's perhaps not too surprising that running the same code several times could give slightly different centres.  You probably still want to re-think using k-means in this case though.  I've edited my answer to make it clear that I don't think this approach is what you want.