# k mean clustering for mixed categorical and numeric value

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, spark-streaming

Any help please

i want to provide a simple framework for identifying and cleaning duplicates data in the context big data . This pretreatment must be performed in real time (streaming).

we reperesent our data base by a file.csv , this file contains patient (medical) records without duplication .

we want to clusterig the file.csv into 4 clusters by using a incremental parallel k mean clustering for mixed categorical and numeric value, each cluster contain similars records.

every time that (data stream) a structured data comes (record), we must compare it with representatives of clusters (M1, M2, M3, M4).............
If the data does not represent a duplicate data , we save it in file.csv , if it represents a duplicate data it is not saved in file.csv.

1)so what's the effiscient tool in my case hadoop or spark !
2) how can i impliment clustering for mixed categorical and numeric value with Mlib(spark) or mahout (hadoop).
3) what does it mean incremental clustering , is that the same of  streaming clustering!

Answer (score 1):

As already noted a dozen of times here on SO/CV:

### k-means computes *means*

unless you can define a least-squares mean for categorical data (that is still useful in practise) using k-means on such data doesn't work.

Sure, you can do one-hot encoding amd similar hacks, but they make the results next to meaningless. "Least-squares" is not a meaningful objective on binary input data.

[KMeans dealing with categorical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328409/kmeans-dealing-with-categorical-variable)

[Why am I not getting points around clusers in this kmeans implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450486/why-am-i-not-getting-points-around-clusers-in-this-kmeans-implementation/17451035#17451035)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58910/kmeans-whether-to-standardise-can-you-use-categorical-variables-is-cluster-3